# How do I disable all user input outside of the application until the user is validated using a two-factor PIN authentication in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, security, winapi

I have a need to disable all user input outside of the application similar to the Windows Secure login prompt where the user cannot do anything until the user is validated. This is by using a PIN card - if the user removes and reenters the PIN card, they need to revalidate again for the application. Our requirement is that the user should not be able to access anything on the machine if the PIN card is removed.

I have set up the secure prompt for CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsA  thinking that this would bring it directly to a secure user login prompt - but it requires the user to hit a button and type CTRL+ALT+DEL to finally get to the prompt. I have also set up a new form for PIN authentication for the application but this only disabled the application. I have thought about using the default windows Lock Screen, but the user can validate using the windows username and password but I still would need the two factor authentication with the PIN card.

Essentially, the process would be:

1. User logs into windows using username and password
2. User is prompted for PIN card when application is opened and user must validate it
3. User is free to use application and other parts of Windows unless card is removed
4. If card is removed, lock the screen until PIN card is revalidate
5. If not revalidate, shutdown application

Does anyone have any alternate solutions where I can essentially lock down the PC until the user can revalidate their card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user would need typing the PIN and other keystrokes, use of `BlockInput` is out of question. One possible idea could be using low level hooks of keyboard and mouse by `SetWindowsHookEx` and checking if the focus is on allowed programs with `GetForegroundWindow`. However it's still a tricky situation and provides only a false sense of security, because a simple boot in safe mode or in a live OS can completely bypass your system, also a malicious program could kill or suspend your process. An attacker with physical access cannot be stopped, now it's HIS machine.